# how to get expired gcloud compute ssh keys?

Tags: ssh, gcloud

I would like to use [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) and then have the keys expired/purged. Any idea how to achieve it?

[EDITED] Just to clarify my question, I am looking for CLI/API that allow me to create or edit SSH key, so it can be integrated into automated solutions.

Answer (score 1):

When you SSH, your public SSH key gets added to the project metadata (for newer instances, this might be the instance metadata, in which case you should substitute `gcloud compute instances describe` and `gcloud compute instances add-metadata`:

```
$ gcloud project-info describe
[...]
- key: ssh-keys
  value: |
     example-user:ssh-rsa <SSH PUBLIC KEY> google-ssh {"userName":"example-user@gmail.com","expireOn":"2017-10-11T17:53:49+0000"}
```

Take a look at the "expireOn" field; you can edit that to a time of your choosing for the key to expire. Some keys may only have the username in place of `google-ssh` (`example-user:ssh-rsa <KEY> example-user@gmail.com`); you can edit those to be in the format above.

Right now, there's no way to set that time up front from gcloud; feel free to [file a request](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues?q=componentid:187143%20status:open) for that feature.

Comment: what CLI command can do it? I know about a way to define it via console. I am looking for a way to integrate it into automation scripts.